# What kind of validations should I use in my db models?

Tags: django, django-models

My form validators are pretty good, and if a form passes is_valid, all data should be ok to insert in the db. Should I still validate something on the db model? What else could there be validated on the db side? Because right now, except maybe for uniqueness ( which I can't do from my FormModel ), I can't think of anything else.

EDIT:
I did some work with Rails earlier, and there you would validate a form on the client side, using JS, and on the server side using model validations. I saw in django you can validate on the client side, using JS, and on the server side you have 2 validation checks: forms and models. This is what confused me.

Comment: You need to post some code if you want any serious guidance. There's not anything anyone can really tell you based on your question right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data should be validated in the database if possible whether you validate from the front end or not. The first validation should be the datatype, for instance using a date datatype will ensure that no nondates can ever get into your database. If you have relationships between tables these absolutely must be enforced at the database level. If the data must be unique, it is irresponsible to not put a unique index on it. If you have a distinct set of values that are the only ones allowed, then put them in a lookup table and add a forign key constraint to that table.

The reason why it is CRITICAL to do validations in the database itself is that the user interface will not be the only thing that interacts with the database (even if you think it will be). Other applications may do so, people will need to make data changes through imports or at a query window (to fix/change large amounts of data such as when client a buys client B and you need to convert all the data to client A). Also if you change the application interface you might lose the some of the critical data integrity checks in the rewrite. Data integrity is one of the most critical factors in database design and maintenance. If you can't count on data integrity, you have no data. I have never seen a database that lets this stuff be handled by the application that didn't lose data integrity over time. Remember the database will far outlast the current application. People will still be looking at this data for years to come. The application typically doesn't consider reporting which is where the data integrity problems tend to come to light. You don't want to have to explain why you have 10,000,000 in orders that you can't identify who they were shipped to, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If your data has a constraint that's always valid, you should force it in the model/database level (and optionally at the form level).  Your DB can be input in multiple ways besides just a form where validation was checked.  E.g., someone can go to the django shell to save models directly or someone could create/edit a model in the admin interface or some later designer creates a new form somehow, that doesn't validate correctly.

Granted this is only required if there are additional constraints on the data.  Django automatically will validate for things like fields storing proper values, if you are using the correct field types.  E.g., `IntegerField` validates to ensure it contains an integer, `EmailField` checks that its entered in the form of a valid email address, `django.contrib.localflavor.us.models.PhoneNumberField` is a US phone number, etc.  Note, this only happens if your models have the proper fields (e.g., if you use `CharField`s for email addresses no validation can be performed.

But there may be other links between data structures, where you should write your own validation.  E.g., if all custom orders requiring special instructions (and non-custom orders only sometimes have special instructions), you should check to enforce all custom orders have something in the special instructions field (and maybe have some minimum length).

---

EDIT: In response to your edit, the reason for three potential validations in django is straightforward -- different validations at different points for different reasons.

Client side (javascript/jquery) validation can't be trusted at all, and should only be given as a convenience for users almost as an afterthought (if you want a spiffy smooth interface).  AFAIK, django doesn't have JS validation unless you use an external package like django-ajax-forms or something, but you don't trust that the validation is correct.

Second, there's a difference between form and model validation.  One model may have multiple forms for different purposes.  For example, you may have a blog with a Comment Model and allow two types of users to comment: signed in users, or anonymous users.  The form for anonymous users may require giving a name/email before they comment, while the form for logged in users doesn't need those fields.  The signed in user form, when processed in a view may automatically add the correct name and email addresses of the signed in user to the comment model before being saved.

In contrast, model validation always applies and will always be true at the database level, regardless of how they tried saving the data.  If you want to make sure some condition always applies make sure it is at the DB level.  (And you don't have to write put that  validation in at the form level).